# How to set app icon for Firebase Auth Google Sign In - In Apps with access to your account section?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have added Google Sign in for my Android app using Firebase Auth and it all works correctly.

However when my user visits https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/permissions to view apps that have access to their account, there is the default logo shown and not my app logo.

[image]

How do I set this logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, I checked today if I am still missing an icon for my app in the Apps with access to your account section, and the icon now appears there. No idea why it fixed itself but now it works. Maybe it just takes some time?